# Javascript uploading duplicates

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload

I have a bit of html with an area where a user can drag and drop files to upload. Nested within, is a "browse for files" button that `clicks()` a hidden file input should they choose the traditional upload method. Everything works well thus far with the exception that if a user drags and drops multiple files (more than one), it uploads each of them twice (3 dropped files uploads 6 files). It does not do this if the user uploads via the browse for files button, so I've narrowed it down to my on `ondrop` function and included that below. I can post additional code if the problem isn't in this code block.

Update: I logged my variable `droppedfile` to the console once before the `for` loop and once after and noticed that when logged after the for loop and 2 files were dropped, the variable contained 2 fileLists and each list contained both of the files (making 4 uploads). How is my `for` loop altering my variable??

```
 dropzone.ondrop = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className = 'dropzone';
    var droppedfile = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    for (i=0; i < droppedfile.length; i++) {
       if(droppedfile[i].type != "text/plain" && droppedfile[i].type != "application/pdf" && droppedfile[i].type != "application/msword"){
           alert(droppedfile[i].type + " file types are not allowed.");
       }else{
           uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
           //calls a function that assigns the file to a new formdata obj and sends via ajax                      
           upload(droppedfile);

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are uploading both the files each time the for loop is executed.
Replace

```
upload(droppedfile);
```

witn

```
upload(droppedfile[i]);
```

Alternatively You can ensure all files are valid before uploading

```
var valid=true;
for (i=0; i < droppedfile.length; i++) {
   if(droppedfile[i].type != "text/plain" && droppedfile[i].type != "application/pdf" && droppedfile[i].type != "application/msword"){
       alert(droppedfile[i].type + " file types are not allowed.");
       valid=false;
   }
}
if(valid) {
   uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';                     
   upload(droppedfile);
}
```

Comment: I just came back to post that I figured this out. I actually moved the function call to upload outside of the for loop. Do you think it would be cleaner if I used try/catch to handle errors where a user drops an unaccepted file type?

Comment: The use of try catch doesn't seem necessary here as you have a simple distinction between a valid and an invalid file. One thing you can do, however, is remove the invalid file from the queue, and enquire whether you can upload the remaining files and go ahead with it. Use try catch if you have some more checks before allowing file upload, such as corrupt files, or files beyond a particular size.